# Py4JJavaError when running write_parquet in pyspark program

Tags: python, java, pyspark

When I run a pyspark program, I'm getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

The particular line of code that causes the error is:

```
# Send to .parquet
write_parquet(df, config.source_path)
```

I've been reading online, and I think it's got to do with the different versions of installations. The relative packages in my Conda env are:

```
findspark 2.0.1
mlflow 1.27
pip 21.2.4
py4j 0.10.9
pylib 1.0.11
pyspark 3.1.2 
python 3.7.13
boto3 1.24.19
```

and the java version is "1.8.0_321"
Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace at all?

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having the same problem